# Cannot call or set a variable from another script in C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

EDIT Full Scripts:
SoldierController Script (removed few variables due to character limitaton). I have declared 1 new variable called DontMove and want this to be called from the ElevatorOpen script. Issue I am having is calling this script even though this is set to static and public.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]
[RequireComponent(typeof(CapsuleCollider))]

public class SoldierController : MonoBehaviour
{
    #region Variables

    public Transform gunPoint;
    public GameObject bulletPrefab;

    //Components
    protected Animator animator;
    private GameObject camera;
    private Camera cam;
    public GameObject splashFX;
    public AudioClip gunShotSound;

    //action variables

    public static bool dontMove = false;
    public float walkSpeed = 1.35f;
    bool canwalk = true;
    float moveSpeed;
    public float runSpeed = 1f;
    public float rotationSpeed = 20f;
    bool isMoving = false;
    public bool walking = true;
    bool areWalking;
    Vector3 newVelocity;
    Vector3 inputVec;

    //aiming/shooting variables
    bool canAim;
    bool canFire = true;
    public bool aiming = true;
    bool isAiming = false;
    public bool grenading = true;
    bool isGrenading;
    bool canGrenade = true;
    int weaponType = 0;

    //Weapon Prefabs
    GameObject pistol;
    GameObject rifle;
    GameObject launcher;
    GameObject heavy;

    #endregion

    #region Initialization

    void Start()
    {
        canMove = true;
        //dontMove = false;
        //set the animator component
        animator = GetComponentInChildren<Animator>();

        //sets the weight on any additional layers to 1
        if (animator.layerCount >= 2)
        {
            animator.SetLayerWeight(1, 1);
        }

        //Get the camera
        camera = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("MainCamera");
        cam = camera.GetComponent<Camera>();

        //sets the Weapon to 1 in the animator
        weaponType = 1;
        StartCoroutine(COSwitchWeapon("Weapon", 1));
    }

    #endregion

    #region Update

    void Update()
    {
            x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
            //z = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
            inputVec = new Vector3(x, 0, z);

        if (animator)
        {
            CoverUpdate();

            JumpingUpdate();

            if (!isSwimming)  //character can't do any actions while swimming
            {
                if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftControl) && canFire && cover != 1 && covering)
                {
                    Fire();
                }

                if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && canFire && cover != 1 && covering)
                {
                    Fire();
                }

                if (Input.GetButton("Fire2") && canAim && aiming)
                {
                    isAiming = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    isAiming = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Fixed/Late Updates

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        CheckForGrounded();

        if (!isSwimming) //character is not swimming
        {
            //gravity
            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(0, gravity, 0, ForceMode.Acceleration);

            if (aircontrol)
                AirControl();

            //check if we aren't in cover and can move
            if (!covered && canMove)
            {
                if (canPushPull)
                {
                    if (!isPushPulling)
                        moveSpeed = UpdateMovement();  //if we are not pushpull use normal movement speed
                    else
                        moveSpeed = PushPull();  //we are push pulling, use pushpullspeed
                }
                else
                    moveSpeed = UpdateMovement();
            }
        }
        else  //character is swimming
        {
            moveSpeed = Swimming();
        }
    }

    void LateUpdate()
    {
        //Get local velocity of charcter
        float velocityXel = transform.InverseTransformDirection(GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity).x;
        float velocityZel = transform.InverseTransformDirection(GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity).z;

        //Update animator with movement values
        animator.SetFloat("Velocity X", velocityXel / runSpeed);
        animator.SetFloat("Velocity Z", velocityZel / runSpeed);

        //if we are moving, set our animator
        if (moveSpeed > 0)
        {
            isMoving = true;
            animator.SetBool("Moving", true);
        }
        else
        {
            isMoving = false;
            animator.SetBool("Moving", false);
        }
    }

    #endregion

    void RotateTowardsMovementDir()
    {
        // Rotation
        if (inputVec != Vector3.zero && !isAiming)
        {
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation(inputVec), Time.deltaTime * rotationSpeed);
        }
    }

    #region UpdateMovement

    float UpdateMovement()
    {
        Vector3 motion = inputVec;

        if (isGrounded)
        {
            //reduce input for diagonal movement
            motion *= (Mathf.Abs(inputVec.x) == 1 && Mathf.Abs(inputVec.z) == 1) ? .7f : 1;

            //apply velocity based on platform speed to prevent sliding
            float platformVelocity = platformSpeed.magnitude * .4f;
            Vector3 platformAdjust = platformSpeed * platformVelocity;

            //set speed by walking / running
            if (areWalking)
            {
                canAim = false;

                //check if we are on a platform and if its animated, apply the platform's velocity
                if (!platformAnimated)
                {
                    newVelocity = motion * walkSpeed + platformAdjust;
                }
                else
                {
                    newVelocity = motion * walkSpeed + platformAdjust;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //check if we are on a platform and if its animated, apply the platform's velocity
                if (!platformAnimated)
                {
                    newVelocity = motion * runSpeed + platformAdjust;
                }
                else
                {
                    newVelocity = motion * runSpeed + platformSpeed;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //if we are falling use momentum
            newVelocity = GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity;
        }

        // limit velocity to x and z, by maintaining current y velocity:
        newVelocity.y = GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.y;
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = newVelocity;

        if (!isAiming)
            RotateTowardsMovementDir();

        //if the right mouse button is held look at the mouse cursor
        if (isAiming)
        {
            //make character point at mouse
            Quaternion targetRotation;
            float rotationSpeed = 40f;
            Vector3 mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
            mousePos = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(mousePos.x, mousePos.y, cam.transform.position.y - transform.position.y));
            targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(mousePos - new Vector3(transform.position.x, 0, transform.position.z));
            transform.eulerAngles = Vector3.up * Mathf.MoveTowardsAngle(transform.eulerAngles.y, targetRotation.eulerAngles.y, (rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime) * rotationSpeed);
        }

        //calculate the rolling time
        rollduration -= rolldamp;

        if (rollduration > 0)
        {
            isRolling = true;
        }
        else
        {
            isRolling = false;
        }

        if (isRolling)
        {
            Vector3 localforward = transform.TransformDirection(0, 0, 1);
            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = localforward * rollSpeed;
        }

        //return a movement value for the animator
        return inputVec.magnitude;
    }

    #endregion

    #region AirControl

    void AirControl()
    {
        float x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        float z = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
        Vector3 inputVec = new Vector3(x, 0, z);
        Vector3 motion = inputVec;

        motion *= (Mathf.Abs(inputVec.x) == 1 && Mathf.Abs(inputVec.z) == 1) ? .7f : 1;

        //allow some control the air
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(motion * inAirSpeed, ForceMode.Acceleration);

        //limit the amount of velocity we can achieve
        float velocityX = 0;
        float velocityZ = 0;

        if (GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.x > maxVelocity)
        {
            velocityX = GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.x - maxVelocity;

            if (velocityX < 0)
                velocityX = 0;

            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(new Vector3(-velocityX, 0, 0), ForceMode.Acceleration);
        }

        if (GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.x < minVelocity)
        {
            velocityX = GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.x - minVelocity;

            if (velocityX > 0)
                velocityX = 0;

            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(new Vector3(-velocityX, 0, 0), ForceMode.Acceleration);
        }

        if (GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.z > maxVelocity)
        {
            velocityZ = GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.z - maxVelocity;

            if (velocityZ < 0)
                velocityZ = 0;

            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(new Vector3(0, 0, -velocityZ), ForceMode.Acceleration);
        }

        if (GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.z < minVelocity)
        {
            velocityZ = GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.z - minVelocity;

            if (velocityZ > 0)
                velocityZ = 0;

            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(new Vector3(0, 0, -velocityZ), ForceMode.Acceleration);
        }
    }

    #endregion

        #region Swimming

    float Swimming()
    {
        Vector3 motion = inputVec;

        motion *= (Mathf.Abs(inputVec.x) == 1 && Mathf.Abs(inputVec.z) == 1) ? .7f : 1;

        //movement is using swimSpeed
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(motion * swimSpeed, ForceMode.Acceleration);

        //limit the amount of velocity we can achieve
        float velocityX = 0;
        float velocityZ = 0;

        if (GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.x > maxVelocity)
        {
            velocityX = GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.x - maxVelocity;

            if (velocityX < 0)
                velocityX = 0;

            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(new Vector3(-velocityX, 0, 0), ForceMode.Acceleration);
        }

        if (GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.x < minVelocity)
        {
            velocityX = GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.x - minVelocity;

            if (velocityX > 0)
                velocityX = 0;

            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(new Vector3(-velocityX, 0, 0), ForceMode.Acceleration);
        }

        if (GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.z > maxVelocity)
        {
            velocityZ = GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.z - maxVelocity;

            if (velocityZ < 0)
                velocityZ = 0;

            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(new Vector3(0, 0, -velocityZ), ForceMode.Acceleration);
        }

        if (GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.z < minVelocity)
        {
            velocityZ = GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.z - minVelocity;

            if (velocityZ > 0)
                velocityZ = 0;

            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(new Vector3(0, 0, -velocityZ), ForceMode.Acceleration);
        }

        RotateTowardsMovementDir();

        //return a movement value for the animator
        return inputVec.magnitude;
    }

    #endregion

    #region PushPull

    float PushPull()
    {
        //set bools
        canAim = false;
        canAbility = false;
        canCover = false;
        canFire = false;
        canGrenade = false;
        canItem = false;
        canJump = false;
        canMelee = false;
        canReload = false;
        canRoll = false;
        canSignal = false;
        canwalk = false;
        isPushPulling = true;

        animator.SetBool("PushPull", true);

        Vector3 motion = inputVec;

        //reduce input for diagonal movement
        motion *= (Mathf.Abs(inputVec.x) == 1 && Mathf.Abs(inputVec.z) == 1) ? .7f : 1;

        //movement is using pushpull speed
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = motion * pushPullSpeed;

        //return a movement value for the animator
        return inputVec.magnitude;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Grounding

    void CheckForGrounded()
    {
        float distanceToGround;
        float threshold = .45f;
        RaycastHit hit;

        Vector3 offset = new Vector3(0, .4f, 0);
        if (Physics.Raycast((transform.position + offset), -Vector3.up, out hit, 100f))
        {
            distanceToGround = hit.distance;

            if (distanceToGround < threshold)
            {
                isGrounded = true;

                //moving platforms
                if (hit.transform.tag == "Platform")
                {
                    //get platform script from collided platform
                    Platform platformScript = hit.transform.GetComponent<Platform>();

                    //check if the platform is moved with physics or if it is animated and get velocity from it
                    if (platformScript.animated)
                    {
                        platformSpeed = platformScript.velocity;
                        platformAnimated = true;
                    }

                    if (!platformScript.animated)
                    {
                        platformSpeed = hit.transform.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity;
                    }

                    //get the platform rotation to pass into our character when they are on a platform
                    platformFacing = hit.transform.rotation;
                }
                else
                {
                    //if we are not on a platform, reset platform variables
                    platformSpeed = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
                    platformFacing.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
                    Platform platformScript = null;
                    float platformVelocity = 0f;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                isGrounded = false;
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Cover

    void CoverUpdate()
    {
        /*
        if (covering && !isSwimming)
        {
            //check if we press cover button
            if (Input.GetButtonDown("Cover") && canCover && !covered)
            {
                //set variables
                animator.SetBool("Moving", false);
                Input.ResetInputAxes();
                isMoving = false;

                animator.SetBool("Moving", false);
                covered = true;
                canReload = true;
                canCover = false;
                canItem = false;
                canMelee = false;
                canFire = false;
                canItem = false;
                canGrenade = false;
                canJump = false;
                cover = 1;
                animator.SetInteger("Cover", 1);
                GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
            }
            else
            {
                //if we are already in cover and press the cover button, get out of cover
                if (Input.GetButtonDown("Cover") && covered == true)
                {
                    //set the animation back to idle
                    animator.SetInteger("Cover", 3);

                    //set variables
                    cover = 0;
                    covered = false;
                    canCover = true;
                    canAbility = true;
                    canAim = true;
                    canItem = true;
                    canGrenade = true;
                    canFire = true;
                }
            }
        }*/
    }

    #endregion

    #region Jumping

    void JumpingUpdate()
    {
        if (!isSwimming) //if character is not swimming
        {
            //If the character is on the ground
            if (isGrounded)
            {
                //set the animation back to idle
                animator.SetInteger("Jumping", 0);

                //set variables
                jumped = false;

                //check if we press jump button
                if (canJump && Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && cover != 1)
                {
                    // Apply the current movement to launch velocity
                    GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity += jumpSpeed * Vector3.up;

                    //set variables
                    animator.SetTrigger("Jump");
                    animator.SetInteger("Jumping", 2);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //set bools
                canDoubleJump = true;

                if (!falling && !jumped)
                {
                    //set the animation back to idle
                    animator.SetInteger("Jumping", 2);
                    falling = true;
                }

                //if double jumping is allowed and jump is pressed, do a double jump
                if (canDoubleJump && doublejumping && Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && doublejumped != true && doublejumping)
                {
                    // Apply the current movement to launch velocity
                    GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity += doublejumpSpeed * Vector3.up;

                    //set the animation to double jump
                    animator.SetInteger("Jumping", 3);

                    //set variables
                    canJump = false;
                    doublejumped = true;
                    isJumping = true;
                    falling = false;
                    jumped = false;
                }
            }
        }
        else //characer is swimming
        {
            //check if we press jump button
            if (canSwim && Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
            {
                if (x != 0 || z != 0)  //if the character movement input is not 0, swim in facing direction
                {
                    // Apply the current movement to launch velocity
                    GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity += swimBurstSpeed * transform.forward;
                    animator.SetTrigger("SwimBurst");
                }
                else  //we are not trying to move the character, jump up
                {
                    // Apply the current movement to launch velocity
                    GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = jumpSpeed * Vector3.up;

                    //set variables
                    animator.SetTrigger("Jump");
                    canJump = false;
                    isJumping = true;
                    canDoubleJump = true;
                    jumped = true;
                    animator.SetInteger("Jumping", 2);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Misc Methods

    void Rolling()
    {
        StartCoroutine(COPlayOneShot("Rolling"));
        covered = false;
        canCover = false;
        cover = 0;
        animator.SetInteger("Cover", 0);
        isRolling = true;
    }

    void Fire()
    {
        StartCoroutine(COPlayOneShot("Fire"));   
        (Instantiate(bulletPrefab, gunPoint.position, transform.root.rotation) as GameObject).GetComponent<BulletController>().damage = 20;
        StartCoroutine(WeaponCooldown());
        GetComponent<AudioSource>().PlayOneShot(gunShotSound);
    }

    IEnumerator WeaponCooldown()
    {
        canFire = false;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
        canFire = true;
    }

    void Ability()
    {
        StartCoroutine(COPlayOneShot("Ability"));
    }

    void Item()
    {
        StartCoroutine(COPlayOneShot("Item"));
    }

    void Grenade()
    {
        StartCoroutine(COGrenade());
        isGrenading = true;
    }

    void Reload()
    {
        StartCoroutine(COReload(weaponType));
        isReloading = true;
    }

    void Signal()
    {
        StartCoroutine(COPlayOneShot("Signal"));
    }

    void Melee()
    {
        StartCoroutine(COMelee());
        isMelee = true;
    }

    void Pain()
    {
        StartCoroutine(COPlayOneShot("Pain"));
    }

    //plays a random death# animation between 1-3
    void Death()
    {
        //stop character movement
        animator.SetBool("Moving", true);
        Input.ResetInputAxes();
        isMoving = false;
        int deathnumber = 5;
        animator.SetInteger("Death", deathnumber);
    }

    #endregion

    #region CORoutines

    //function to play a one shot animation 
    public IEnumerator COPlayOneShot(string paramName)
    {
        animator.SetBool(paramName, true);
        yield return null;
        animator.SetBool(paramName, false);
    }

    //function to switch weapons
    public IEnumerator COSwitchWeapon(string weaponname, int weaponnumber)
    {
        //sets Weapon to 0 first to reset
        animator.SetInteger(weaponname, 0);
        yield return null;
        yield return null;
        animator.SetInteger(weaponname, weaponnumber);
    }

    //function to reload
    public IEnumerator COReload(int weapon)
    {
        //sets Weapon to 0 first to reset
        animator.SetBool("Reload", true);
        yield return null;
        animator.SetBool("Reload", false);
        float wait = 0;

        if (weaponType == 1 || weaponType == 2)
        {
            wait = 1.85f;
        }

        if (weaponType == 3 || weaponType == 4)
        {
            wait = 3f;
        }

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(wait);
        isReloading = false;
    }

    //function to grenade
    IEnumerator COGrenade()
    {
        //sets Weapon to 0 first to reset
        animator.SetBool("Grenade", true);
        yield return null;
        animator.SetBool("Grenade", false);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        isGrenading = false;
    }

    //function to Melee
    IEnumerator COMelee()
    {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        canMove = false;
        isMoving = false;
        animator.SetTrigger("Melee");
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(.7f);
        isMelee = false;
        canMove = true;
    }

    IEnumerator COKnockback()
    {
        StartCoroutine(COPlayOneShot("Knockback"));
        return null;
    }

    public IEnumerator CODazed()
    {
        StartCoroutine(COPlayOneShot("Dazed"));
        Debug.Log("Cant Move");
        canMove = false;
        canFire = false;
        canAim = false;
        canJump = false;
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3.0f);
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        canMove = true;
        canFire = true;
        canAim = true;
        canJump = true;
    }

    #endregion

    #region WeaponSwitching

    void WeaponSwitch()
    {
        weaponType++;

        if (weaponType == 1)
        {
            //enables pistol, disables other weapons
            pistol.SetActive(true);
            rifle.SetActive(false);
            launcher.SetActive(false);
            heavy.SetActive(false);
            StartCoroutine(COSwitchWeapon("Weapon", 1));
        }

        if (weaponType == 2)
        {
            //enables rifle, disables other weapons
            pistol.SetActive(false);
            rifle.SetActive(true);
            launcher.SetActive(false);
            heavy.SetActive(false);
            StartCoroutine(COSwitchWeapon("Weapon", 2));
        }

        if (weaponType == 3)
        {
            //enables launcher, disables other weapons
            pistol.SetActive(false);
            rifle.SetActive(false);
            launcher.SetActive(true);
            heavy.SetActive(false);
            StartCoroutine(COSwitchWeapon("Weapon", 3));
        }

        if (weaponType == 4)
        {
            //enables heavy, disables other weapons
            pistol.SetActive(false);
            rifle.SetActive(false);
            launcher.SetActive(false);
            heavy.SetActive(true);
            StartCoroutine(COSwitchWeapon("Weapon", 4));
        }

        if (weaponType == 5)
        {
            //enables pistol, disables other weapons
            pistol.SetActive(true);
            rifle.SetActive(false);
            launcher.SetActive(false);
            heavy.SetActive(false);
            StartCoroutine(COSwitchWeapon("Weapon", 1));
            weaponType = 1;
        }
    }

    #endregion

}
```

And finally the elevatorOPen script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ElevatorOpen : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Animator animator;
    public AudioClip ElevatorBing;

    void Awake ()
    {
        animator = GetComponent <Animator>();
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter (Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player") {
            animator.SetInteger ("Open", 1);
            GetComponent<AudioSource>().PlayOneShot(ElevatorBing);
        }
    }
    void OnTriggerExit (Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player") {
            animator.SetInteger ("Open", 0);
            SoldierController.dontMove = true;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the lower one should work... what error do u get with that?

Comment: Hi Andrew,
I get the following error:

`SoldierController' does not contain a definition for `dontMove'

Comment: You likely have another error around there.

Comment: thats the error for the top one. If the lower one didnt work it would say that `SoldierController doesn't contain a static member dontMove`

Comment: I commented out the variable from the soldiercontroller and from the elevatoropen and no other errors appear.

Comment: okay so its working then.. don't try and confuse us because the problem won't be solved that way

Comment: No its not resolved.  I commented out the variable, but that doesnt mean its resolved. I want that variable to be in the soldier controller and be able to call it from the elevatoropen script

Comment: For the lower one, did you change SoldierController to a static class?  Be careful with 'static' though.  If you leave your dontMove property static, all your soldiers will either move or be stationary.  You won't be able to have each one behave differently than the others.

Comment: Hi WDS, yes I have left it as static for the moment. Only reason I have it I have it set is because I dont want my character to move in the elevator. After a number of seconds (once the elevator transition has happened), the character will be able to move again (dontmove=false).

Comment: I'm afraid you are going to need to post more code for me to tell you what's wrong.  In the top one, it looks like you are creating an instance of SoldierController and naming it Player.  By the way, by convention instances of a class start with a small letter and the class name itself starts with a capital.  That said, without seeing the SoldierController class, it is hard to do more than guess.

Comment: But if I had to take one guess here (regarding the top version which is the better approach) my guess is that you accidentally put the public static bool dontMove = false; line inside one of the class's methods, so it is not in scope from outside the class.

Comment: Did you verify that SolderController is saved?

Comment: Can you add both classes with the relevant code (ie, remove the all code but the code that you had posted before), keeping the structure of the classes ? (ie; public class SoldierController {public static bool dontMove = false; // etc...  }

Comment: @WDS `public` modifiers dont compile from inside of methods

Comment: @Andrew good call.  I'm not sure then.  Would still love to see the Class definition though just in case the problem is rooted there in some other way.

Comment: Added the full code (had to remove excess variables in order to get the full code in)

Comment: SoldierController player = GetComponent<SoldierController>();
StartCoroutine(player.CODazed());

This works for calling IEnumerator from the ElevatorOpen script, but why cant I call a simple variable which seems to be doing my nut in

Comment: your problem is that don't move is a static property, which means it is inherent to the class, but not the instance of that class.  So basically you cannot change the value of this property without redefining the class itself, so there is no setter for this property.  Change don't move to not be static and you will be able to change the value

Comment: Hi theDarse,

I have changed public static bool dontMove = false; to public bool dontMove = false;

but same error occurs

Comment: @theDarse no thats not true you can change the value of `static` properties as long as they are not read-only

Comment: I am totally stumped.  If I make a non-static class with a non-static, public property and try to modify the property on an instance of that class, I have no errors.

Answer (score 0):

This has been addressed. This is a bug with Unity 5 Beta - Spoke to a member of staff who provided me the latest version of Unity, which has fixed the issue.